# How does the Teamviewer Android App gets the screen

Tags: android

in a project I want to send the screen of my Android device to a remote service. There are some possibilities how to do that. For example copy the grafic memory (root required) or get the current bitmap of my app. 
Anyway either I need root rights or I only get the screen of my own App. I saw that the Teamviewer app does something like that too.

At the end my question. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just make a screenshot, send it to the other phone(or to a server). Make a screenshot 2x a second, and I think it will look fine. If you really want to know how Teamviewer does it, you have to decompile the .apk file(ofcourse, at your own risk).

Comment: Which is illegal in most countries

Comment: I really don't get it. Why would it be illigal? You only learn code if you do that.

Comment: Because the TeamViewer APK contains closed-source code by TeamViewer, it's theirs, not anyone else's. Open source code in the other hand is up to that kind of thing. In any case APK decompiling is shady at best, legal-wise.

Comment: Even if you get it decompiled, you wouldn't learn much from it because it is most likely obfuscated by ProGuard. So if a class called `A` with the methods `a()` and `b(B ba, C bb)` helps you learning, I'm not sure if you still need to learn something about code :D